# Is it possible to have different default values in children content-types?

Tags: content-type, inheritance, default-value

We would like to use inheritance in our content type setup, where the parent content type has a field "subtype".

We would like to have default values in our children content types defined on the content type level (not a library or list).

Is that possible? And if yes, how?

Example:
Parent content type is "Car", Children are "Sports Car" and "Truck", with some additional metadata. The "car type" column is inherited from "Car", but should default to "Sports Car" and "Truck".

Comment: after a quick check, I don't think that's possible at the CT level.  But more importantly, you have some redundancy in your architecture.  Do you really need both a content type and a car type that contain the same information?  Could you get by with one or the other?  If I create a new "Truck" but change its car type to "Sports Car" is that a valid scenario?

Comment: Derek, thank you. My example might be a bit oversimplified. I was just wondering if it is possible :) How would you deal with default values that might be different on a sub-type or sub-site level?

Comment: The defaults can be set at the list level or even all the way up at the site column level. You'll need to find a way to achieve your goal using those.  If you really need more flexibility than that you could look into either an event receiver or JavaScript running on the new form.  Either of those approaches will introduce more complexity into your solution so be mindful of that.